# Unable to see snowflake conn_type in Airflow

Tags: airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I can see the following in my pip list but when I try to add a Snowflake connection via the GUI, Snowflake is not an option from the dropdown.

apache-airflow-providers-snowflake 2.1.0
snowflake-connector-python         2.5.1
snowflake-sqlalchemy               1.2.3

Am I missing something?

Comment: Which Airflow version do you have installed?

Comment: Are you running Airflow on MWAA ?

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same issue using the official helm chart 1.3.0.
But finally I was able to make Snowflake connection visible by doing the following steps:

1. I uninstalled the apache-airflow-providers-google. Not sure whether this is important, but I like to mention it here. I did this, because I got some warnings.
2. Because with SQLAlchemy 1.4 some breaking changes were introduced, I made sure that version 1.3.24 gets installed. Based on that I choosed the fitting version for snowflake stuff.

So this is my requirements.txt for my custom Airflow container:

```
apache-airflow-providers-snowflake==2.3.0
pyarrow==5.0.0
snowflake-connector-python==2.5.1
snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.2.5
SQLAlchemy==1.3.24
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.2.1-python3.8

## adding missing python packages
USER airflow
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip uninstall apache-airflow-providers-google -y \
  && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Because of incompatibillity warning between pyarrow (4.1) and snowflake-connector-python I bumped up pyarrow to 5.
So I updated the requirements.txt.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue with MWAA recently.
I find that if I select AWS in the drop down and provide the correct snowflake host name etc it works though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where my pip freeze showed the `apache-airflow-providers-snowflake` yet I did not have the provider in the UI. I had to add the line `apache-airflow-providers-snowflake` to my `requirements.txt` file and then restart. Then I was able to see the Snowflake provider and connector in the UI.